# How to check wired network connection

Tags: networking, debian

Using Debian 10 (buster).
I'm connect to the router using cable.
Most of the times - after I enter the cable there is no connection (the network-manager icon seems to be in process of connection [Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0elCH.png), and after some time I got message: "Connection failed - activation of network connection failed").
How could I check if this is hardware problem (although later its working without changing the hardware) or software problem, or maybe problem with the router?
There is no any error in dmesg